# How can I pass ids to colorbox?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, colorbox

Colorbox is not recognizing ids of random elements when clicked on , it alerts ids in ascending order when you click on elements randomly .. How can I make it so the right id is displayed when clicking on whatever element ?

**JavaScript Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.madscore").colorbox({
        inline:true, 
        width:"350px", 
        href: "#madcomment_menu"
    });

    $("div#scoring_scale a").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        ID = $(this).attr('id'); 
        alert(ID); 
        point = $(this).text(); 
        username = $('#username'+ID).val(); alert(username);
        name = $('#name'+ID).val(); 
        image = $('#image'+ID).val(); 

        //var message = $('textarea#text'+ID).val(); alert(message);
        var result ='Just gave @'+username+' a score of'+point+'via MadFlock';
        $('textarea#text'+ID).attr("value", result);
        tweet = $('textarea#text'+ID).val(); 
    });
});
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    $select  = "SELECT * FROM COMMENTS INNER JOIN Twitter_Data ON Twitter_Data.screen_name=Comments.Twitter WHERE Category ='Comments'";

    $result = mysql_query($select);
    $result_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    echo " <table border =\"0\">";
    echo "<tr>";

    $user_array = array();
    $counter = 0;

    if($result_count > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {  
            echo  "<div id ='scoring_scale' class='madscore".$row['ID']."' style='display:none;'>";
            echo "<div id='madcomment_menu' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>";
            echo "<a id='".$row['ID']."' class='green_circle' href='#'> +3 </a>";
            echo "<a id='".$row['ID']."' class='orange_circle' href='#'> +1 </a>";
            echo "<a id='".$row['ID']."' class='red_circle' href='#'> -1 </a>";
            echo "<a id='".$row['ID']."' class='brown_circle' href='#'> -3 </a><br />";
            echo"<form>";
            echo "<textarea id='text".$row['ID']."'rows='5' cols='33'>";
            echo "-";
            echo "</textarea>";
            echo"<button id='button".$row['ID']."'class='button_madscore'> MadScore </button>";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }

    // Here is the link that will generate the COLORBOX pop-up   
    echo "<a id='".$row['ID']."'class=' madscore' href='#madcomment_menu'><img src='images/madcomment.png' /> </a>";
?>
```

Comment: no I still havent solved it .. no one is answering

Comment: ok , I will delete it and repost the HTML output